# Using enable_if on virtual functions

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, sfinae, enable-if

```
#include <type_traits>

class Base {
public:
    virtual bool f() {
        return true;
    }
};

template<typename T>
class Derived : public Base {
    std::enable_if_t< std::is_copy_constructible<T>::value, bool > f() override {
        return true;
    }

    std::enable_if_t< !std::is_copy_constructible<T>::value, bool > f() override {
        return false;
    }
};
```

The above code doesn't compile. For some reason I did not manage to understand, the compiler sees the two functions as the same overload before removing one by SFINAE.

What I do not understand, however, is how I am to resolve this problem. The docs I found [state](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) I should use templating on the function. That doesn't work, however, because the function is meant to be virtual.

I tried off-loading the problem by calling a non-virtual function, but I cannot get that to compile either:

```
template<typename T>
class Derived : public Base {
    virtual bool f() override {
        return f_impl();
    }

private:
    template< std::enable_if_t< std::is_copy_constructible<T>::value > = 0 >
    bool f_impl() {
        return true;
    }

    template< std::enable_if_t< !std::is_copy_constructible<T>::value > >
    bool f_impl() {
        return false;
    }
};

int main() {
    Derived<int> a;

    std::cout<<a.f()<<"\n";
}
```

That fails compilation with:

```
so.cpp: In instantiation of ‘class Derived<int>’:
so.cpp:29:18:   required from here
so.cpp:18:10: error: ‘std::enable_if<true, void>::type’ {aka ‘void’} is not a valid type for a template non-type parameter
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong here, but I can't figure out what would be the correct way.

Comment: Why don't you just return a value `bool f() override { return std::is_copy_constructible<T>::value; }`?

Comment: Because this is a simplified example. In actuality, I need to do two very different things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do that. [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) works with templates; e.g. the following code revised from your 2nd sample works.

```
template< typename X = T>
std::enable_if_t< std::is_copy_constructible<X>::value, bool >
f_impl() {
    return true;
}

template< typename X = T>
std::enable_if_t< !std::is_copy_constructible<X>::value, bool >
f_impl() {
    return false;
}
```

[LIVE](https://rextester.com/KJDT59452)

But `virtual` functions can't be template, that's all.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why this solution with `std::is_copy_constructible<T>` doesn't work?

Comment: @ShacharShemesh `std::enable_if` should depend on the template parameter of the function template itself. Otherwise, SFINAE won't work; both the `f_impl` would be instantiated and either would be ill-formed certainly.

Answer (score 4):

Using `if constexpr` it is possible to branch inside of function at compile time so function can stay `virtual`:

```
bool f() override
{
    if constexpr(std::is_copy_constructible<T>::value)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I do `if constexpr(false) nonExstingFunction();` ? Because this is a simplified example.

Comment: @ShacharShemesh It would be similar to the non-instantiated template - inactive branch won't be present in the body of the compiled function but syntax should be valid.

Comment: Since the `true` branch of the if needs to actually call the copy constructor, I'm afraid this solution won't work for me. There I was, hoping C++ introduced `static_if` without me noticing....

Comment: @ShacharShemesh it is indeed `static_if` and if does not work for you then variant with a template won't work either

Comment: so if I got this correctly, the `false` side of the `if constexpr` needs to be syntactically correct, but it does not need to be semantically correct. It may reference non-existing functions and variables?

Comment: that does not seem to be the case. `int main() {
    if constexpr(false)
        nonexisting();
}
` does not compile (nonexisting not declared).

Comment: @ShacharShemesh No, all the names used in the both branches must refer to some known entities. It is the same for templates. Temples don't allow referencing non-existing functions and variables even when they are not instantiated. Copy constructor of `T` type could be used in true branch `if constexpr(std::is_copy_constructible<T>::value)` without triggering an error when it is not actually available.

Comment: So I can call a non-existing overload of an existing function, but not a function which is completely undeclared. That's very far from a true `static_if`, unfortunately.

Comment: If you want the static_if from D, #ifdef is your friend (for this usage)

Comment: Note `if constexpr (false)` doesn't work, however, it you can use another templated function that always returns false, it does work: `if constexpr (Fake<T, false>::value)`

Comment: @JVApen `if constexpr (false)` should work without problem, condition does not need to be dependent on template parameters.

Comment: Is it? Cause it doesn't hold for the content (like static assert), I'll test it

Comment: @JVApen argument of `static_assert` does not need to be dependent on template parameters either. But `static_assert(false)` simply makes program invalid.

Comment: @JVApen the use case here does not translate well to `#ifdef` at all. The condition is compile time known, not during preprocessing.

Comment: In that case, the value ain't just `false`, it's dependent on T. In which case you are good